# Ember partials and actions

Tags: ember.js

I have this issue trying to use an ember partial and an action that targets the view

```
...
<li class="buttonsList-item-horizontal btn btn-lg btn-secondary" {{action restore this target='view'}}>
  <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
  <span class="btn-text">Restore</span>
</li>
...
```

If I use this code inside a partial is not working if I use it directly in the template it works.
Any ideas or suggestions to accomplish the same result?

the template is

```
...
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list-item list-item-separator">{{group.key}}</li>
    {{#each content}}
      {{partial 'templateElement'}}
    {{/each}}
</ul>
...
```

Comment: it should work...maybe a jsbin link would help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about the view, and not the template which you called the view above you have the logic correct.

```
App.IndexView = Em.View.extend({
  actions:{
    blah:function(){
      console.log('asdf');
    }
  }
});

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <ul>
  {{#each item in model}}
    <li>{{partial 'foo'}}</li>
  {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>


<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="foo">
  <button {{action 'blah' target='view'}}>{{item}}</button>
</script>
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/hocanilu/1/edit

Comment: yes sorry I was talking about template and not view

Comment: actions should be in quotes, but in my example it's working, will you show your view, route, and associated controller.